# How to balance "Zone of Peace"

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review

I am playing a pacifist paladin in a fantasy campaign. I am trying to create a "Zone of Peace" spell that prevents everything in the zone from attacking. Currently, my idea is that the user rolls charisma, and all creatures have to roll above that number on their attack rolls to succeed. It also has a duration of 1 round (Or about 5 minutes). Is this balanced? And if not, how do I balance it?

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about we operate here. Please also review [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/how-should-i-ask-about-my-dd-5e-homebrew-being-balanced) about how to ask for balance on homebrew as well as the links inside that meta for more information. At this point, your homebrew isn't yet defined and needs to be fully developed before we can help. Once you have 20 rep, you can also hop into [chat] where you may find some additional help.

Comment: What level is the character, and what oath has the paladin taken (if of sufficient level)  Also, what spells does the paladin have, and do you have Xanather's Guide to Everything? (It's not a core  book, but it's got some interesting material)

Comment: Are your fellow party members and players OK with this kind of interference? If not, no amount of mechanical balancing will make this spell viable.